# Finding the mean and standard deviation of a R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataFrame called df like :

```
temp1     temp2
  4         3
  3         6
  4         5
```

How can I find the mean and standard deviation of this whole R dataFrame? I tried this

```
mean(as.matrix(df))
```

but I get this error:

```
In mean.default(data) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Comment: are you looking for `mean(unlist(data))`?

Comment: could you please show how your desired output should look like

Comment: `mean(as.matrix(df))` should work. Are `temp1`and `temp2` the column names? Is the dataframe entirely numeric? And why do you have an error message referring to `data` when the name of your dataframe is `df`?

Comment: @Veerendra Gadekar and @ RHertel  it actually works, I made a slight typo error. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Of the two suggestions from comments, the `as.matrix` method appears superior:

```
microbenchmark(unlist = mean(unlist(iris[,1:4])), 
                 as.matrix = mean(as.matrix(iris[,1:4])))
## Unit: microseconds
##       expr    min      lq      mean  median      uq     max neval cld
##     unlist 236.82 237.961 245.47638 239.102 240.812 374.807   100   b
##  as.matrix  58.54  60.440  67.38185  61.961  68.613 273.694   100  a
```